# Using angular, why can't I display an error in the view when the url for the http request isn't correct, despite including an error handler?

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, error-handling

I have a service, component, and a template for that component as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnIrp.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/boRj4.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/029ni.png

The component class does have a closing bracket, but it follows from a set of methods which had nothing to do with my problem. I've also imported all the modules I'm using for my code, even if they're not displayed in the images. I'm actually able to successfully connect to my backend server when I use the right url, and am able to list all the information below the button I get from that server. But for some reason, when I use a nonsense url like I did in the first image I posted, a 404 error doesn't get registered. Even a console.log within the errorHandler doesn't get triggered. I got this way of handling errors from a YouTube video, so perhaps that information is out of date. Anyway, I'd really appreciate an answer. I'm also using Ionic as a framework on top of angular, so perhaps that might have to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Typescript didn't like that I used a newline and a lot of white space between the first subscribe function and the second. Here's the fix:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA9zq.png